# How to add a space from outside an extended partition to a logical partition contained in the extended partition?

Tags: grub2, partitioning, gparted

- First, my partitioning looks like so:

[image]

- I do not like how it looks, and am not sure how I came up with that  extended partition `sda3`[****] which I do not need, but it did not bother    me initially, so I continued with that structure.
- At a certain point I have shrunk the Windows partition and used the new partition to test different Linux-es. Now, that is called `sda2`.
- I am not sure if I use the terminology properly, but `sda2` is my  only linux partition outside the large extended partition. (As far as I understand it, an extended partition is like a container for smaller partitions: in a way `sda3` contains and is formed  by sda5, 6 and7.)
- I have used `sda2` to test different Linux OS-es. At a certain point, when `sda7` was not a system partition, but an empty one, I have tried to enlarge `sda2` into `sda7` but this was not possible - I think because `sda7` was within the extended partition `sda3`. So, I just copy/pasted the `sda2`, which was a system partition into the free `sda7` (with Gparted) and in this way have transferred the system to a larger partition. But now **I would like to enlarge even more `sda7` (now my system partition): and cannot do it**. I would like to use `sda2` which now is separated and kind of useless.
- `sda5` is a space to deposit files.

---

My question is:

**Is it possible to change this structure of my partitions so as to add `sda2` space to my system partition `sda7` without having to remove my system - that is: without formatting  `sda7` and `sda5`?**

---

I am familiar with Gparted booting from external USB and with Boot Repair. So, I do not mind if solving this would corrupt the grub, I could restore it later with Boot Repair. I just want to now what would be the chances of adding the space of `sda2` to the system partition.

---

[****I am under the impression, although not really sure, that the structure of `sda3` as extended partition is the result of the manipulations made while installing/testing different Linux-es on `sda2` and that the partitioning program of the system installer was able to change the record entries of what now are sda5, 6 and 7 without formatting them: so, I hope to do something like that from a bootable GParted USB].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To add a space from outside an extended partition to a logical partition contained in that extended partition, that space has to be *first* included in the extended partition.**

Only then it can be added to one or more of the logical partitions from within the extended one.

So:

1. Using **GParted** from a **live CD/USB**, **delete sda2** which is EMPTY.
2. **Resize sda3 (extended) partition to the left** to take up all the unallocated free space left by sda2.
3. You can then use the **new unallocated free space before sda7** in any way you like:

   - increasing the size of sda7 (*preferably by making a backup of this
     partition first, e.g. using clonezilla or redo* although GParted should perform this without any problems), after which you can
     even share some of the newly gained space with other partitions (sda5
     & sda6) in several steps of moving their start boundaries to the
     left, or
   - creating a new partition there

Comment: This is the tricky part of Extended Partition, which is regarded as one Primary Partition. First, you must resize it (sda3). Second, you can only then resize Logical Partitions contained in it (sda7,6,5).